# Cannot associate Salesforce Data Extensions to Contact Model, what is the workaround?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Here's some background, I am in a child business unit in an account that has been set up with MC Connect. To get the sync'd data from the parent to the child, I have an automation that pulls data from the sync'd Contact_Salesforce DE, and places it in a DE under the Salesforce Data Extensions folder. This is needed because my client wants all email sends that are performed from MC to get recorded in SalesCloud.

The question, within the child BU, I now need to reference this data in a Journey, but cannot update the Contact Model because it does not allow references to Salesforce Data Extensions. Does this mean I need to create another DE in the standard Data Extension folder, and update my automation to also copy sync'd data there? Essentially meaning I'll have two copies of the same data, one in the Data Extension folder, and the other in the Salesforce Data Extension folder, is this right?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that filtering the Synchronised Data Extension into the Salesforce Data Extension folder, and sending from there will allow the tracking to go back to Sales Cloud.

It should be possible to link the Synchronised Data Extension directly in Contact Builder without having to refer to the Salesforce Data Extension.  Once it's connected in Contact Builder, you should be able to reference it in Journey Builder.